# Updating popup of a Leaflet Polygon

Tags: leaflet, leaflet-draw

I am trying to update a popup for a polygon that I have drawn with `Leaflet.Draw`. Now I understand that to set a popup to a layer I just created, it's all fine. I can also get the id of that layer I just created using the `L.stamp(my_layer)`.

Let's say I create 3 layers: A, B and C. Each of them has their stamp id stored in my database. Now let's say at some point I want to bind  a popup to layer C. How do I access that layer C when I click on it and bind the popup to C only?

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you have stored your "stampID" in your database.

I suggest you to put the stampID into each of the GeoJSON layer as a FeatureCollection  Properties Name or something that you can alter which has been created from `Leaflet.Draw`.

Assuming that you have that done. Probably you can make use of this syntax if it is set as FeatureCollection Properties Name, for example: `layer.features.properties.name`

You also can use this Leaflet Method:

- layergroup: https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.4.html#layergroup
- layergroup's getLayer:
  https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.4.html#layergroup-getlayer
- featuregroup: https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.4.html#featuregroup

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you add the drawn layers to a `drawnLayers` `L.FeatureGroup()`, you can bind a listener to those polygons and then bind popups on click:

```
//event function
function onclick(e) {
  e.layer.bindPopup('A popup!');
}

//bind listener to layers
drawnLayers.once("click",onclick) //fires only for the first polygon you click on
                                  //drawnLayers.on("click",onclick) would fire always when you click on the polygon
```

I have modified an existing jsfiddle to include this code snipped: https://jsfiddle.net/5t1vpy4n/